# /deep/ selector в Angular 5

Tags: angular5

Мне необходимо изменить mat-tab-group. Использую deep

```
/deep/ .mat-tab-label .mat-tab-label-content {
    color: white;
}
```

Цвет меняется, но проблема в том что он меняется и у другого mat-tab-group. Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить класс для нужного компонента:

```
<mat-tab-group class="someclass">
```

И в css:

```
.someclass /deep/ .mat-tab-label .mat-tab-label-content {
    color: white;
}
```